# Unable to rotate or flip variable capacitor, according to expectation

Tags: circuitikz

I am trying to get this

[image]

but even though i tried `mirror` `xscale=-1` `yscale=-1`...

I am still unable to get the expected result, how come.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american,cuteinductors,siunitx,smartlabels]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) node[rxantenna, xscale =-1]{} coordinate (Antenna)
    to [short, *-] ++(0,1)
    to [short, -*] ++(2,0) coordinate (C1)
    to [vC, yscale=-1, *-] ++(0,-2)
(C1)
    to [short] ++(2,0)
    to[generic,n=S1] ++(0,-2)
    to [short] ++(-2,0)
    to [short] ++(-2,0)
    to [short] (Antenna)
    ;
     \speaker{S1}{0}
;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, it's like `yscale` asn't any effect !!!

Don't get me wrong here, `yscale=-1` did in fact flip the capacitor as you can see i had to chage my connetion end from `-*` to `*-` in

`to [vC, yscale=-1, *-] ++(0,-2)`

But the arrow is still pointing down.

Why? and how do i fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrow always points from anchor point `in` to `out`.  You fix it by reversing the order in which it is drawn.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american,cuteinductors,siunitx,smartlabels]{circuitikz}

\newcommand{\speaker}[2]    % #1 = name from to[generic,n=#1], #2 = rotation angle
{\draw[thick,rotate=#2] (#1) +(.2,.25) -- +(.7,.75) -- +(.7,-.75) -- +(.2,-.25);}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) node[rxantenna, xscale =-1]{} coordinate (Antenna)
    to [short, *-] ++(0,1)
    to [short, -*] ++(2,0) coordinate (C1)
    to [short] ++(2,0)
    to[generic,n=S1] ++(0,-2)
    to [short, -*] ++(-2,0) coordinate (C2)
    to [short] ++(-2,0)
    to [short] (Antenna)
  (C2) to[vC] (C1);
    \speaker{S1}{0}
;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]